# How to pass a function as parameter to Promise in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, closures

When trying to write a wrapper class for asynchronous DynamoDB calling, I failed with the attempt to wrap all the return statements with a function call as:

```
function composePromise(method: (params: any, callback: (err, res) => void) => void, params: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) =>
        method(params, (err, res) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(res);
        })
    );
}

create(params: any): Promise<any> {
    return composePromise(this._db.put, params);
}
```

Which is strange, because after I move the promise in `create` without any change, it works.

```
create(params: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) =>
        this._db.put(params, (err, res) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(res);
        })
    );
}
```

So I am guessing it might be some closure issue, but cannot figure out why. Could anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `this._db.put` is probably a shortcut to some other function declared on `this._db`, if so then the method is probably using `this` and that's where it fails.

You should bind the correct context to that function

```
create(params: any): Promise<any> {
    return composePromise(this._db.put.bind(this._db), params);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Will this `bind` function will persist `this` in it's closure so that it can be find when later invoke this function?

Comment: sorry but I don't understand your question, which context are you referring to? the `bind` function creates a wrapper function without modifying `this._db.put`